# Complicated sql statement with 4 conditions inside

Tags: mysql, sql

I´m trying to query the sql from the table below. I have tried many ways to get the job done.But seemed like it too complicate for me to find the solution.

**user_id="200";** // let´s say the user id now is 200.

tb_conversation

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
c_id   |   user_one_id   |   user_two_id   |   user_one_delmsg    |   user_two_delmsg
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
001    |      200        |      198        |          Y           |        N
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
002    |      195        |      200        |          Y           |        N
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
003    |      200        |      193        |          N           |        N
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I´m trying to do is to query the only one table which match with the **user_id** above.
And it can be user_one or user_two in the table. if the user_id is user_one in the table then, user_one_delmsg must not be "Y".  OR   if the user_id is user_two in the table then, user_two_delmsg must not be "Y"

**What I have tried :**

```
$q= "SELECT * from conversation  ORDER BY c_id DESC ";
$_stmt = $conn->prepare($q);
$_stmt->execute();
$row=$_stmt->fetchAll();


foreach ($row as $r) {

if ($user_id==$r['user_one_id']){
    if ( $r['user_one_delmsg']!="Y") {
    //do something

    }
}

if ($user_id==$r['user_two_id']){

    if ( $r['user_two_delmsg']!="Y") {

        //do something

    }
    }
```

**What I get is:**
array of result that match the query.
**But** what I want is only one result that´s the max c_id and user_**x**_delmsg must not be "Y"

I have also use only fetch(); I did not get what I want.
I have also put the limit 1 in the last of query, but it did not help.

Comment: what is the result you want? is it 3? what is the type of column `c_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a given userId, try

```
 Select Max(c_id) from conversation 
 Where 200 in (user_one_id, user_two_id)
     And (user_one_id <> 200 Or user_one_delmsg <> 'Y')
     And (user_two_id <> 200 Or user_two_delmsg <> 'Y')
```

for all UserIds, try:

```
Select userId , Max(cid) From
 (Select c_id cid, user_one_id userId 
  from conversation
  Where user_one_delmsg <> 'Y'
  Union
  Select c_id cid, user_two_id userId 
  from conversation
  Where user_one_delmsg <> 'Y') Z
Group By UserId
```

Comment: I does not work either :S Do you think because of pdo ?
I have replaced the 200 to $user_id

Comment: When I remove the Max out, it work ! but it did not give me the top id :S

Comment: What error did you get with the `Max()` in there ?  That's what gives the top id.

Comment: Now I wonder one thing...suddenly the method one you gave me just work fine without the Max..Why ?  And If so why do we need the Max then ? Please explain me .

Comment: Without the max, it will only work if there is only one conversation which satisfies the criteria.  If there is more than one, all of them will be returned, not just the one with the highest c_id

Answer (score 0):

This will select max(c_id) and will check for user_one_delmsg not equal to y.

```
select max(c_id), user_one_id from conversation where user_one_delmsg!='y';
```

This will select max(c_id) for both user_one_id and user_two_id(specifically 200 mentioned) and will check for user_one_delmsg.

```
select max(c_id), user_one_id from conservation where user_one_id='200' and 
user_one_delmsg!='y' union select max(c_id), user_two_id from conservation where 
user_two_id='200' and user_two_delmsg!='y';
```

Comment: @PoramatFin ok, But please edit your question and mention the desired output, this would be helpful for other others to answer.

Answer (score 0):

try to use the following query

```
SELECT MAX(c_id) FROM tb_conversation
   WHERE (user_one_id=200 AND user_one_delmsg='N')
      OR (user_two_id=200 AND user_two_delmsg='N')
```

check this [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35f5e/2/0)